# Pass the index of the active slide when changed, vuejs 3 ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework, slide, vuejs3

I'm trying to pass the index of active slide when he change, in ionic-framework using vuejs 3, but i don't know how.

Someone can please help me?

```
<ion-slides :options="slideOpts" @ionSlideDidChange="SomeAction()" >
   <ion-slide v-for="(item, index) in imgsSrc" :key="index">
      <img :src="item" alt="" srcset="" > 
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

I try to use `getActiveIndex()`, the native method, with `ref="slider"` but i get an error saying that  `getActiveIndex()` is not a function.

```
    methods:{
    SomeAction(){
      console.log(this.$refs.slider.getActiveIndex());
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

After the slides are initialized and loaded, get the object and assign it to a ref in the `didLoad` function; you will then have access to the Swiper object and can utilize the documented API if you like

```
<ion-slides
  @ionSlideDidChange="change"
  @ionSlidesDidLoad="didLoad"
  :options="slideOpts"
>
  <ion-slide v-for="(item, index) in ['1', '2', '3', '4']" :key="index">
    <div class="my-slide">
      <p>item {{ item }}</p>
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
```

````
  setup() {
    const _swiper = ref<any>(null);
    return {
      slideOpts: {
        speed: 400,
      },
      _swiper,
      didLoad: (e: any) => {
        _swiper.value = e.target.swiper;
        console.log(_swiper.value);
      },
      change: () => {
        console.log(_swiper?.value?.activeIndex);
      },
      router: useRouter(),
    };
  },```
````